# Cache form data against page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, django, caching

I have certain forms in my Django project and I want to get a different data with a button on this form with a pop-up window and save it to the database. But here, how can I make the previously entered data come back when the page is reloaded so that my background data is not lost?

Thanks in advance to everyone who helps.

Comment: Why don't you use `localstorage` or `cookie`?

Comment: Look into `localStorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage Edit: As @DreamBold suggested `cookies` are also a valid option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage has a `setItem` method. You can use it like this:

```
var inputEmail= document.getElementById("email");
localStorage.setItem("email", inputEmail.value);
```

When you want to get the value, you can do the following:

```
var storedValue = localStorage.getItem("email");
```

It is also possible to store the values on button click, like:

```
<button onclick="store()" type="button">StoreEmail</button>

<script  type="text/javascript">
  function store(){
     var inputEmail= document.getElementById("email");
     localStorage.setItem("email", inputEmail.value);
    }
</script>
```

To use `cookie` instead, you can refer to [this](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/#:%7E:text=The%20process%20of%20setting%20the,you%20to%20the%20next%20page.) article.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem("name", "Smith");
localStorage.getItem("name");
localStorage.removeItem("name");
```

You can use localStorage, This data can be available in developer Tool=>application Tab => localstorage